# Why isnt ActionListener working?

Tags: java, netbeans, actionlistener

Why isn't this `ActionListener` working? I've tried to follow tutorials but I keep getting the same error.

```
public class listenerTest implements ActionListener {
@Override //<-- This adds another error
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println("Message"+e.toString());
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

And in the other file:

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new listenerTest());
```

NetBeans says

```
there are compilation errors on listenerTest class "listenerTest is not abstract and 
does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener"`
```

and the error on `@Override` says `method does not override or implement a method from supertype`.

Any help how to fix this?

Comment: Can you rename your class to use the appropriate name convention standards? I mean, instead of "listenerTest", try "ListenerTest".

Comment: did you import `import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;` ?

Comment: dont mix up swing and javafx `ActionEvent` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had mixed up JavaFX and AWT ActionEvent imports.
Thanks, @Reimeus!

Answer (score 1):

Add this two lines top of your class :

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```